# document.getElementById working differently on iPad Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ipad, mobile-safari

I'm getting completely different behaviors in mobile Safari on the iPhone versus the iPad, both on actual hardware and in the iOS simulator, for document.getElementById.

This works on mobile and desktop but not on the iPad:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
foo.innerHTML = 'bar';
```

Actually, setting foo.[anything] isn't working on the iPad.

Website: https://davero.com/order2

Banging my head bloody. All help will be appreciated.

Comment: Actual (partial) code:

document.getElementById('item_descrption').innerHTML = json.description;
document.getElementById('item_image').src = json.image_url;

Doesn't matter whether I use an intermediary variable to hold the document.getElementById() result.

Comment: Solved. Problem between user and keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using safari on the desktop to? Safari has had a problem before where it will return null or undefined back instead of the object.
Try using jQuery instead which would look like $('foo');
It would also be really helpful if you could post your code or atleast where you tagged foo and your script.

Comment: Yes -- using Safari on the desktop without difficulty, as well as on the iPhone.  Problem is exclusive to all iPads (hardware as well as the iOS Simulator vi Xcode).  I'll post code snippet above.